# Elasticsearch Rest Client with Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am in a situation where I am using Spring boot and AWS elasticsearch service. AWS Elasticsearch service which only provides REST interface.

Elasticsearch Rest Client is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_initialization.html).

Simply, Is it possible to use REST client with Spring Data Elasticsearch?

In other words, Does Spring Data Elasticsearch works with Elasticsearch Rest client?

Spring Data Elasticsearch is very easy to use and template provides very most functionality that I need. With Elasicsearch Rest client I have to implement all the functionality myself.

Comment: Elastic Search has released High Level Rest Client and its good to build quarries dynamically :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**[2020 May Update]**

https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/27/what-s-new-in-spring-data-elasticsearch-4-0

As you can read Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0:

> Spring Data Elasticsearch now uses Elasticsearch 7, 7.6.2 in particular. Elasticsearch clusters running on 6.x versions are not supported anymore. The ElasticsearchTemplate class is deprecated as it uses the TransportClient to access Elasticsearch, which itself is deprecated since Elasticsearch version 7.+ Users should switch to ElasticsearchRestTemplate or ReactiveElasticsearchTemplate.

**[2019 February Update]**

A see now that 3.2.0 M1 Spring Data Elasticsearch supports the HTTP client (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.0.M1/reference/html/#reference)

According to the documentation (it could of course change because it's not final version so I will put it here):

> The well known TransportClient is deprecated as of Elasticsearch 7.0.0 and is expected to be removed in Elasticsearch 8.0.
>
> 2.1. High Level REST Client
>
> The Java High Level REST Client provides a straight forward replacement for the TransportClient as it accepts and returns the very same request/response objects and therefore depends on the Elasticsearch core project. Asynchronous calls are operated upon a client managed thread pool and require a callback to be notified when the request is done.

Example 49. High Level REST Client

```
static class Config {

  @Bean
  RestHighLevelClient client() {

    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder() 
      .connectedTo("localhost:9200", "localhost:9201")
      .build();

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest(); 
  }
}

// ...

IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("spring-data", "elasticsearch", randomID())
  .source(singletonMap("feature", "high-level-rest-client"))
  .setRefreshPolicy(IMMEDIATE);

IndexResponse response = client.index(request);
```

---

**[Original answer]**

Currently Spring Data Elasticsearch doesn't support the communication by the REST API. They are using the transport client.

There is separate fork of Spring Data Elasticsearch (the guy needed it for AWS the same as you) where the JEST library is used and communication is made by REST:

https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-data-jest

You will find the interesting discussion under the following ticked of Spring Data Elasticsearch:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-220

I think the Spring Data Elasticseach will need to migrate to REST on the future according to the statements from Elasticsearch team that they are planning to support only HTTP communication for ES.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is there any news? does Spring Data Elasticsearch supports REST API in the latest versions?

Comment: How can one use High Level Rest Client in Spring Data ES 3.2.0.M1? see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754790/how-to-use-high-level-rest-client-in-spring-data-es-3-2-0-m1

Answer (score 1):

I think jest client for elasticsearch will serve your purpose. https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/tree/master/jest. Jest is a Java HTTP Rest client for ElasticSearch. It has a very good documentation too and  have support for all queries in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on Przemek Nowak's answer above. If you don't want to wait for Spring Data ES 2.2.x to use the High Level Rest Client, then [Spring Data Jest](https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-data-jest) saves the day.

As per their documentation, you first disable the default Spring Data ES autoconfiguration:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class, 
    ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

And that's it - the repositories will now use Jest's implementation. And if you'd like to use the `ElasticsearchTemplate`, make sure you inject `ElasticsearchOperations` interface instead:

```java
private final ElasticsearchOperations esTemplate;
```