# Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.0.RELEASE with Rest Client

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.0.RELEASE was released a few days ago on Oct. 2, 2017. Is there any update with supporting the REST client in that release?

This relates to this question: [Elasticsearch Rest Client with Spring Data Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134811/elasticsearch-rest-client-with-spring-data-elasticsearch/)